# Python Tkinter loop to change button color on Enter and on Leave (python 3.4, Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating some buttons using Tkinter's "place" function.  I want to have them appear gray when the user hovers over them, and then back to black when the cursor leaves.  I am able to do this by binding them explicitly, but I want to bind them dynamically with a loop.  The loop I tried to create is at the bottom of the code, but it doesn't work.

This code will run in python if you would like to see what I'm talking about.

How can I create a dynamic loop to do this?

```
from tkinter import *

FONT_SIZE = 14  # Change this to change all font sizes in the program

root = Tk()

root.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)
root.geometry("800x600")
root.config(background="black")

# Labels
newGameButton = Label(root)
loadGameButton = Label(root)
optionsButton = Label(root)
exitButton = Label(root)
Labels = [newGameButton, loadGameButton, optionsButton, exitButton]

#Changes the background of buttons when you hover over them
def changeBGEnter(widget):
    widget.config(background="gray")
#Changes the background of buttons when you stop hovering them
def changeBGLeave(widget):
    widget.config(background="black")

# Explicit bindings, ugly
newGameButton.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: changeBGEnter(newGameButton))
newGameButton.bind("<Leave>", lambda x: changeBGLeave(newGameButton))

loadGameButton.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: changeBGEnter(loadGameButton))
loadGameButton.bind("<Leave>", lambda x: changeBGLeave(loadGameButton))

optionsButton.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: changeBGEnter(optionsButton))
optionsButton.bind("<Leave>", lambda x: changeBGLeave(optionsButton))

exitButton.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: changeBGEnter(exitButton))
exitButton.bind("<Leave>", lambda x: changeBGLeave(exitButton))

# New Game Button
newGameButton.config(
    anchor=CENTER,  # Where to anchor the text in the widget
    background="black",
    foreground="white",
    font=("default", FONT_SIZE),
    text="NewGame",
)

newGameButton.place(
    relwidth=0.6,
    relheight=0.1,
    relx=0.2,
    rely=0.3
)

# Load Game Button
loadGameButton.config(
    anchor=CENTER,
    background="black",
    foreground="white",
    font=("default", FONT_SIZE),
    text="Stats",
)

loadGameButton.place(
    relwidth=0.6,
    relheight=0.1,
    relx=0.2,
    rely=0.4
)

# Options Button
optionsButton.config(
    anchor=CENTER,
    background="black",
    foreground="white",
    font=("default", FONT_SIZE),
    text="Output",
)

optionsButton.place(
    relwidth=0.6,
    relheight=0.1,
    relx=0.2,
    rely=0.5
)

# Exit Button
exitButton.config(
    anchor=CENTER,
    background="black",
    foreground="white",
    font=("default", FONT_SIZE),
    text="Exit",
)

exitButton.place(
    relwidth=0.6,
    relheight=0.1,
    relx=0.2,
    rely=0.6
)

#Code I want that doesn't work:
#Get rid of explicit bindings above to test the code below
"""
for x in Labels:
    x.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: changeBGEnter(x))
    x.bind("<Leave>", lambda x: changeBGLeave(x))
"""

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. bind send `event data` as first argument in `lambda` so `x` is `event data`, not label.
2. (in `for` loop) lambda doesn't copy value from `lab` to `changeBGEnter(lab)` (but use `lab` as reference and all `changeBGEnter` got the same, last label) so you have to copy it using `label=lab`

.

```
for lab in Labels:
    lab.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, label=lab: changeBGEnter(label))
    lab.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, label=lab: changeBGLeave(label))
```

-

(by the way: you could create own widget to make it simpler)

---

**EDIT:** own widget `MyButton` with binded `<Enter>` and `<Leave>`

```
from tkinter import *


class MyButton(Label):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.changeBGEnter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.changeBGLeave)

    def changeBGEnter(self, event):
        self.config(background="gray")

    def changeBGLeave(self, event):
        self.config(background="black")


FONT_SIZE = 14  # Change this to change all font sizes in the program

root = Tk()

root.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)
root.geometry("800x600")
root.config(background="black")

# Labels
newGameButton = MyButton(root)
loadGameButton = MyButton(root)
optionsButton = MyButton(root)
exitButton = MyButton(root)
Labels = [newGameButton, loadGameButton, optionsButton, exitButton]

# New Game Button
newGameButton.config(
    anchor=CENTER,  # Where to anchor the text in the widget
    background="black",
    foreground="white",
    font=("default", FONT_SIZE),
    text="NewGame",
)

newGameButton.place(
    relwidth=0.6,
    relheight=0.1,
    relx=0.2,
    rely=0.3
)

# Load Game Button
loadGameButton.config(
    anchor=CENTER,
    background="black",
    foreground="white",
    font=("default", FONT_SIZE),
    text="Stats",
)

loadGameButton.place(
    relwidth=0.6,
    relheight=0.1,
    relx=0.2,
    rely=0.4
)

# Options Button
optionsButton.config(
    anchor=CENTER,
    background="black",
    foreground="white",
    font=("default", FONT_SIZE),
    text="Output",
)

optionsButton.place(
    relwidth=0.6,
    relheight=0.1,
    relx=0.2,
    rely=0.5
)

# Exit Button
exitButton.config(
    anchor=CENTER,
    background="black",
    foreground="white",
    font=("default", FONT_SIZE),
    text="Exit",
)

exitButton.place(
    relwidth=0.6,
    relheight=0.1,
    relx=0.2,
    rely=0.6
)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** but you can use `tkinter.Button` to get the same result without own widget or loop.

And you can use `command=` to assign function to button click.

```
exitButton = Button(root)

def command_exit():
    print "exit"
    root.destroy()

exitButton.config(
    anchor=CENTER,
    font=("default", FONT_SIZE),
    text="Exit",

    # Leave colors
    background="black",
    foreground="white",

    # without border    
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,

    # Enter colors
    activebackground="grey",
    activeforeground="white",

    # run on click
    command=command_exit
)
```